# Import only new articles from Joomla to Wordpress

Tags: plugins, import, cms, bulk-import

Is there a way to only import articles created in Joomla after a specific date to Wordpress?

I'm trying to export only articles made in Joomla after a certain date to wordpress. Currently, we have imported all Joomla content to Wordpress using FG Joomla to WordPress Premium, and we've done quite a bit of work reorganizing categories and getting the content ready to publish live. We're getting closer to going live, but have been continually updating the Joomla website as we go with new articles. We're now looking into how to import only the new articles to the dev Wordpress site without overwriting or creating duplicates.

What I've tried: I can't find an option in FG Joomla to Wordpress to do this. I've looked briefly at other plugins, but found no good options, all other plugins for this seem to be around 50x less popular than FG Joomla to Wordpress by number of installs and have dubious ratings. If I get no suitable answer on here, we can always set up a second wordpress, import everything and then export only what we need, but that seems like it might be unnecessary, and we'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how FG Joomla works, but seems like it should be providing a csv or sql file of some sort.  Why not just open that up and delete the old posts that way before re-importing into wordpress? Maybe it has an option to remember you last import and not over write the same posts created by the previous import?

Or if that doesn't work, you could Un-publish all the posts that are in your current wordpress install (set as draft), and then do the import, all you have to do then is delete all the published posts in wordpress that older than the date you needed. Once you've deleted all the "older" posts, just set all posts back to active.

You could likely just tag them as well and use the same idea.